# InputMethodManagerService exception on Unity + Android app for google glass

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-gdk

I'm developing a shooting game for google glass using Unity3D. I'm subclassing UnityPlayerNativeActivity in order to capture tap gestures (implementing onKeyDown (..)) and send them to Unity using UnitySendMessage in order to "shoot" inside the game. Everything works fine, but from time to time (randomly) the shooting mechanism stops working. I've seen the following exception regarding InputMethodManagerService on logcat:

```
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529): Session failed to close due to remote exception
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:292)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1365)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1356)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1382)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1401)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1115)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1129)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1239)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1362)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
05-05 15:52:44.637: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputEventSender(6062): Failed to send motion event sample on channel 'ClientState{212ab268 uid 10055 pid 6062} (server)'.  status=-32
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManager(6062): Unable to send input event to IME: com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME dropping: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=823.0, y[0]=81.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4338362, downTime=4338284, deviceId=1, source=0x100008 }
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputEventSender(6062): Failed to send motion event sample on channel 'ClientState{212ab268 uid 10055 pid 6062} (server)'.  status=-32
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManager(6062): Unable to send input event to IME: com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME dropping: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=823.0, y[0]=81.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4338388, downTime=4338284, deviceId=1, source=0x100008 }
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529): Session failed to close due to remote exception
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:292)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1365)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1356)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1382)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1401)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1115)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1129)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1239)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1362)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
05-05 15:52:44.661: W/InputMethodManagerService(529):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 15:52:44.677: E/(6062): B: 1
05-05 15:52:44.677: D/InputMethodManagerService(529): --- calledFromForegroundUserOrSystemProcess ? calling uid = 10055 system uid = 1000 calling userId = 0, foreground user id = 0, calling pid = 6062com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.startInput(InputMethodManagerService.java:1250)
```

Any idea how to prevent/fix this or any work-arround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the code that creates this generates this error output?

Comment: Hi! No code. Te exception just pumps up ramdomly when the app is launched (not always). As you can see by the Exception Stack, the problem is not originated on the app code itself.